# pass selected option value with an id via URL

Tags: javascript, php

I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to pass the value of option value in the `select` through the URL with the `id`.But I'm having trouble with implementing the logic to send the option value in the URL itself with the `id`.I know that I can send the value using `POST` method. But if I use `POST` method how can I pass `id` to the model.

This is the code that contains the select options and the URL that I'm trying to pass the parameters.

```
 <div class="table-responsive" ">
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <td>#</td>
        <td>Task</td>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $data = new tasks();
    $set = $data->get();
    foreach ($set as $row) {

        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $row['id'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['name'] ?></td>
            <td>
                <select name="status" id="status">
                    <option value=""><?= $row['status'] ?></option>
                    <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
                    <option value="Currently Working">Currently Working</option>
                    <option value="Have To Start">Have To Start</option>
                </select></td>
            <td>
                <a href="task.php?status=<?= $row['status'] ?>&id=<?= $row['id'] ?>" type="submit"  class="btn btn-update" name="update">Update</a>
                <a href="task.php?delete=<?= $row['id'] ?>" type="submit"  class="btn btn-delete" name="delete">Remove</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you want the `href` in those links to change when the user selects an option in that `<select>`?  That would be done with JavaScript, not PHP, since it's client-side logic.

Comment: Yes!! I want to change the value when user selects an option.I have no idea on how to implement that in JS. can you please guide me through? or suggest any tutorial that I should go through?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use onchange event on select box
check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)

so in your case it may be

```
onchange="document.location.replace('task.php?status='+this.value+'&id=<?= $row['id'] ?>');"
```

Comment: Thank you.I have a doubt.SO if i use `onchange` should I remove the `href` that has for the update button and replace it with your code?

Comment: no, that is for the select box to work right after you choose something in there without clicking anything else. But if you want to have that button, then you need to register the id for every single status select box, then assign onclick event on that update button to send the id to the method to get the value from status and then send that in JS

Comment: does that means that the `href` of update button gets overwritten by the function?

Comment: I saw your updated comment.I'm still confused.Is it possible for you to provide me an example in your answer it self?

Comment: so, do you want to update status by extra click on a or just by change of status box itself ?

Comment: I want to update the url based on the value that user select from the dropdown options